# Suppose $f(x,y)$ and $\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}$ are continuous in a neighborhood. Show $g(x,y) = \int_{a}^{x}f(t,y)dt$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Suppose $f(x,y)$ and $\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}$ are continuous in a neighborhood of $(a,b) \in \mathbb{R}^{2}$. Show $g(x,y) = \int_{a}^{x}f(t,y)dt$ is $\mathcal{C}^{1}$ in a neighborhood of $(a,b)$.

So in order to accomplish this I have to show that $g(x,y)$ is continuous and its derivative $g'(x,y) = Dg(x,y)$ is continuous. I know it is a manipulation of some sort using the properties of the fundamental theorem of calculus and Leibniz differentiating under the integral theorem. But I just can't seem to make all come together. Could I get some help?

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
\dfrac{g(x+h,y)-g(x,y)}{h}&=\dfrac{1}{h}\int_{x}^{x+h}f(t,y)dt=\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}(\eta_{x,h},y),
\end{align*}
where $\eta_{x,h}$ is chosen by Integral Mean Value Theorem, lies in between $x$ and $x+h$, when $h\rightarrow 0$, continuity of the partial derivative gives the limit $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ at the point $(x,y)$.

Comment: what happened to the constant $a$ on the lower part of the integrand?, Also we haven't learned the MVT for integrals either...

Comment: $\displaystyle\int_{a}^{x+h}-\int_{a}^{x}=\int_{a}^{x}+\int_{x}^{x+h}-\int_{a}^{x}$.

Comment: $f(c)=\dfrac{1}{b-a}\displaystyle\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx$ for continuous function $f$.